# Getting IPV4 Address from newly setup Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I setup my raspberry pi zero w Version 1.1 by following this link
https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-zero-creation/install-os-on-to-sd-card

And I tried pinging it...

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping raspberrypi.local

Pinging raspberrypi.local [fe80::f92d:dbcc:b9e4:18cb%24] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::f92d:dbcc:b9e4:18ab%25: time=20ms
Reply from fe80::f92d:dbcc:b9e4:18ab%25: time=25ms
Reply from fe80::f92d:dbcc:b9e4:18ab%25: time=23ms
Reply from fe80::f92d:dbcc:b9e4:18ab%25: time=18ms
```

is there a way to get the IPV4 address without going into the router setup?

Comment: `ping -4 raspberrypi.local`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, so that is how it is.  Don't know much about networks.  Sorry for such a noob question.  I basically started on my RPi journey and that first link was the first one I saw in my google search.

Comment: Welcome.  There's nothing inappropriate about your link, I think Milliways jumped the gun a bit there (I apologize on his behalf).  Anyway, it sounds like your question has been resolved; if you or @JaromandaX want to write the solution up briefly as an answer (you may have to wait 24 hours to answer your own question), that would be great.